# Applying style inside html helper in .net mvc3

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm using .net mvc3

In the view I need to do this:

```
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.SearchForm.Exact, (text1 text2))
```

the problem is that text1 should be bold and text2 shouldn't.

Is it possible to do something like <strong>text1</strong> text2 inside the helper?

Thanks,

Fernando

Comment: Go for  normal html labels..That way u can customize

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new extension method for your needs:

```
    public static MvcHtmlString LabelFor<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> html, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression, string text1, string text2) {
        ModelMetadata metadata = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, html.ViewData);
        string htmlFieldName = ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression);
        string labelText = metadata.DisplayName ?? metadata.PropertyName ?? htmlFieldName.Split('.').Last();
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(labelText)) {
            return MvcHtmlString.Empty;
        }

        TagBuilder tag = new TagBuilder("label");
        tag.MergeAttributes(htmlAttributes);
        tag.Attributes.Add("for", html.ViewContext.ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldId(htmlFieldName));

        // here you create your needs and add to the label

        return MvcHtmlString.Create(tag.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal));
    }
```